# Add NSDictionary to existing NSMutableArray - Swift

Tags: swift, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have been attempting for a while now to add in an extra dictionary value into a **NSMutableArray** containing **NSDictionaries** at each index.

I have tried several approaches detailed below.

```
func findDistanceAndSortArray(offers : NSMutableArray){

    for (index, offer) in enumerate(offers) {

        var json = JSON(offer)

        if let location = json["company"]["address"]["location"].dictionary {

           //Not important Location code is here <----- 

            var distance = self.calculateDistance(newLat, longitude: newLngg)

            var newDistance = ["totalDistance" : distance]

            // I have tried these ....
            // offers.insertObject(newDistance, atIndex: index)
            // offer[newDistance]
            // json["totalDistance"] = "" <-- this inserts the dictionary but I cannot add a string into ANYOBJECT

        }
        println("MORE inside \(json)")
        println("MORE inside \(offers)")

    }
}
```

The closest I got was using `json["totalDistance"] = ""` which inserted the value alongside its key but when I tried to add in the string it produced a error saying can't add string to value type JSON (As I am using SwiftyJson for parsing)

Can't seem to figure this one out but I'm sure its simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thirst: you must not change an array while iterating thru the same array. Because you tried to:

```
// I have tried these ....
// offers.insertObject(newDistance, atIndex: index)
```

And the solution should be:

```
json["totalDistance"].string = distance
```

Please try, I currently have no compiler to test it.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you. I just need to figure out how to convert json back to a nsaray.

Comment: Back to NSArray? I don't understand.